# flutter: Cannot open file, path = (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2), for ios simulator at reboot, works for android simulator

Tags: flutter, dart, filesystems

I am using `path-provider` package to store an image in a local device directory.

After i have the image placed, if I reboot my ios simulator, i get an error as below. If I do the same in Android simulator, i.e. store an image in local database and after reboot, try to use that image, i don't see this issue. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

The Flutter code, which I am using to read the image is `FileImage(File(snapshot.data.imagePath))` and `snapshot.data.imagePath` is a String.

The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:

```
 Cannot open file, path = '/Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04ED29D2-275B-4156-88DF-8BE54DA61E8D/data/Containers/Data/Application/14322A84-EAD6-430C-A6A6-4F2551E06AD5/Documents/image_picker_5C9947E8-F51B-4E2E-97D0-C2103E84C3DE-11307-0000062A227CFD28.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

```
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FileImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:884:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 2 frames from dart:async)
```

Comment: can you manually check once if the file is located within the same location ?

Comment: yes, i checked. File is located at same location. And the issue only occurs at reboot. If I hot restart the app, I do not see this issue.  Not sure, if this is simulator problem or IDE problem. My code works perfectly if i dont reboot.